# How does Android integrate hardware drivers provided by the phone manufacturer?

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I heard that the drivers are provided by the phone manufacturer. So I'm wondering whether the system.img I compiled from the Android source code includes the drivers or not. If it does not, where are the drivers? Is it possible that I re-flash the drivers?

Thanks!

Comment: @ hebothu  AFAIK this question does not belong here. I don't know the right StackExchange site for such questions else would've migrated the question to the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to install the drivers on your own for some devices if you are on a PC. You can go to that phone manufacturer's website and they have a download link. Mac seems a little better in finding the device drivers

Comment: The OP is not asking about drivers on the computer. THe question is about drivers on the device with with the Android OS interfaces with hardware like GPS, screen et,etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I'm asking is where the drivers are. For example, I downloaded a full Android package (sojua-grk39f) for my Nexus S, which includes boot.img, recovery.img, system.img, userdata.img, bootloader-xxx.img and radio-xxx.img. Are the drivers included in some of these .img files? Thanks :)